# How to capture macro names in C?

Tags: c, string, macros

Suppose I have a library exposing hundreds of macros like these:

```
#define EVENT_X 0
#define EVENT_XYZ 1
#define EVENT_123 2
...
```

I would like to offer to the library user a way to access these macros by name.  I don't know how to do this given that macro names are gone by the time the preprocessor is done.

Concretely: how can I create a function `event_name(int event_value)` which displays the event name so that:

```
event_name(EVENT_X);
event_name(1);
```

displays

```
"X"
"XYZ"
```

I can do this a non-elegant and error-prone way by defining an array in my library where I define the name of each of these macros manually:

```
const char* EVENT_NAMES[] = {
  "X",
  "XYZ",
  "123",
  ... }
```

in which case my function `event_name` can simply be:

```
void event_name(int event_value) {
  printf("%s\n",EVENT_NAMES[event_value]);
}
```

But with hundreds of macros, it's painful and error-prone to create manually that `EVENT_NAMES` array.

A slightly more robust solution is to create that array as follows:

```
const char* EVENT_NAMES[] = {
  STRINGIFY(EVENT_X),
  STRINGIFY(EVENT_XYZ),
  ...
}
```

with `#define STRINGIFY(X) #x`

But that does mean removing at run time the "EVENT_" *and* I still need to re-list all macros manually when creating EVENT_NAMES, being at the risk of forgetting some macros or permuting them.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: What about using an enum like `enum EVENT {X, XYZ};` and then just `STRINGIFY(XYZ);`?

Comment: your first way is the way it's realisticaly done

Comment: If there are gaps (e.g. there is no event 5, but 4 and 6), you might want to do it like this

`const char *EVENT_NAMES[] = {
 [EVENT_X] = STRINGIFY(EVENT_X),
 [EVENT_Y] = STRINGIFY(EVENT_Y)
};`

Comment: Do they have to the pre-processor  `#defined` macros or would enums work?

Comment: Does values of the defines are only integer numbers?  
Are their successive, or with rare and tiny holes, or any number?
Depending on that there may be a solution defining "simultaneously" some enumaration values and array to convert to user readable text

Comment: You do it as in your first description, but you don't do it "manually".  You have your build system generate the array for you.

Comment: why can't you use a `static map <int, const char*>` instead of assuming array index to be the value of macro. 
You can populate this map in the startup, and it will not be error prone as well.

Comment: @Yogesh Because: wrong programming language. Also even if C++ was an option then `std::map` is using run-time heap allocation and is generally slow as heck, in comparison to compile-time macros and direct access LUT.

Comment: you need logic beyond the horizon of macros - so if you insist in doing it with macros, I think, you are lost. But if not, your library could supply an ENUM containing all the values (feeling nearly like macros for the user) and wrap the creation of the enum values with a macro CREATE_EVENT(name,value) in the header file for the user and a diffferent implementation of this same macro for the libraries internal usage (again sourcing the lib's include file) to indeed additionally create the string assignments e.g. in the lib's init().

Comment: The beauty bugs are warnings about redefinition of this macro while compiling your lib and maybe your user could get doublicate symbols (did play this till the end). Maybe theres a way in conjunction with typedef of the enum to avoid the dup symbols also. but at least, you define the values only once and bypass inconsistencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering therefore that here no need to have #define, and the event values can be considered as little consecutive integral numbers.

It is impossible in C to simultaneously define enumeration values and an array describing these values.

But defining everything without risk of inconsistencies is still possible.
We have the preprocessor that works on texts and can read files.
First create a file named for example "events.inl" (it's not really a header or a code file), the file must only contains lines like:

```
DEF_EVENT(   X, 0  )          // EVENT_ prefix must not be here
DEF_EVENT( XYZ, 1  )
DEF_EVENT( 123, 12 )
```

Next we'll #include this file to generate the enum somewhere and the array somewhere else:

```
// define events as enum, all events are named EVENT_...
//======================
#define DEF_EVENT(name,value) EVENT_##name = value,
enum {
    #include "events.inl"
};
#undef DEF_EVENT

// the array for user access
//==========================
#define DEF_EVENT(name,value) [value] = #name,
const char* const  EVENT_NAMES[] = {
    #include "events.inl"
};
#undef DEF_EVENT
```

If there is no event for a value, there is a NULL pointer in the array.

The definitions can be in any order and the size of the array is still acceptable if the values are small non-negative numbers.

Edit :
We can avoid the file using a big macro, and just replace the #include(s) by that macro:

```
#define ALL_DEF_EVENTS    \
  DEF_EVENT(   X, 0  )    \
  DEF_EVENT( XYZ, 1  )    \
  DEF_EVENT( 123, 12 )
```

Comment: That's pretty neat, defining twice DEF_EVENT with different meanings. I will see if other answers come up, but at first sight, I like what you propose.

Comment: The technique is called x-macros.  You can search for that.  Wikipedia [X Macro](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) for example.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thanks for the link. Inside we can see how to simply adapt my sample to avoid this nasty intermediate file.